# Manually installing tensorflow on windows

Tags: python, tensorflow, installation, pip, anaconda

I tried to install tensorflow on my Windows machine by `pip install tensorflow`, but the installation failed inbetween with following error

> ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [SSL: DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC] decryption failed or bad record mac (_ssl.c:2622)

I also tried to get tensorflow through Anaconda Navigator, but then I get the following error-

> UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be
> incompatible with the existing python installation in your
> environment:
>
> Specifications:
>
> - tensorflow -> python[version='3.5.*|3.6.*|3.7.*']
>
> Your python: python=3.8
>
> If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version
> you've asked for. When python appears to the right, that indicates
> that the thing on the left is somehow not available for the python
> version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not change your
> python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly
> specify that.

I am looking for a safer to to install tensorflow, preferably a manual way where I can download the package and install it (to avoid any chances of network disruptions).

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: As mentioned in the error, you'll need to have a Python version between 3.5 and 3.7.

Comment: The website mentions the Python requirement 3.5 to 3.8 and pip version >19.0; both the requirements are satisfied. None of the above method worked, if not Anaconda, then pip should have worked.
If this is indeed the case, can I rollback python to 3.7 (is that possible)?

Comment: Can't say much for Anaconda, but `pip install` fails because you have an unstable internet connection. You can try downloading the [wheel file](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/61/e1/1e713485caee272e7be779ac10bb0cec36ace3d9f981e067a9105a736791/tensorflow-2.3.1-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl) by to local FS, then install via `pip install path\to\tensorflow.whl`

Comment: Will this work - downloading https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow and `pip install .`?